# How to get Adapter position in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

In the **list view**, I have the object of my POJO class so if I want to fetch an object's position in the list view it can get by below code

```
mAdapter.getPosition(object)
```

but I cannot find any solution to get an `Adapter` position with the help of my object in the **recyclerview**

Please help me for the same.

Comment: use `getAdapterPOsition()` inside your adapter to get position

Comment: Simple. Use _getAdapterPosition()_

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the position via `mAdapter.getPosition(object)` in case of recycler view. But if you really want the position via object then, you can get it by:

```
array.indexOf(obj);
```

here array is your array list which content you are setting to the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Use  last param of onBindViewHolder() method of Adapter class for get position

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FavourtieViewHolder favourtieViewHolder, int position) {
   // like this
   POJO obj=list.get(position);

// using Adapter holder class object you can also get position
 int pos=favourtieViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

}
```